# pandas: give arbitrary number of column values as input to function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that calculates the markov probability from a transition matrix of events. I used *args to create it in such a manner that I can provide it an arbitrary number of events:

```py
def get_prob(*args):
    ret = 1
    for i, j in zip(args, args[1:]):
        ret *= probs.at[i,j] # probs is the dataframe of probabilities

    return ret
```

To use get_prob, I need to give the names of the events in single parentheses and separated with a comma:

```py
get_prob('RegainStart','RegainReady','Programstopped','RegainStart')
Out[77]: 0.00039915615879420366
```

Probs is an dataframe with the transition matrix of events which looks like this:

```py
                  RegainStart    RegainReady    ProgramStopped
RegainStart       0.30           0.20           0.10
RegainReady       0.80           0.34           0.20
Program Stopped   0.29           0.45           0.60
```

In another dataframe called Rules, I have some sequential patterns that I have found with the C-SPADE algorithm. These results are stored in this dataframe:

```py
    Sequence             
0   RegainStart,RegainReady,Programstopped,RegainStart
1   RegainStart,RegainReady
2   RegainStart,RegainReady,RegainStart
3   Programstopped,RegainStart
```

My problem is as follows: I want to hand the values of each row of the Rules dataframe to the get_prob function and calculate the markov probability. However, I cannot seem to get the input right. I tried the following to get the strings of the first row:

```py
list(rules['sequence'].str.split(',', expand=True, n = 1).iloc[0])

Out[70]: ['RegainStart','RegainReady,Programstopped,RegainStart']
```

It only stripped the first comma and not the others coming after the first. In addition, it still is not correct input for the get_prob function, which just needs those separate strings as input:

```py
get_prob('RegainStart','RegainReady','Programstopped','RegainStart')
```

Am I approaching this correctly or am I missing some function of pandas/python that supplies those rows as input for my function?

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, this should work for you:

```
probs = df['Sequence'].str.split(',').apply(lambda s: get_prob(*s))
```

The statement splits each string sequence into a list and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) the `lambda` function on each list (see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for more about unpacking argument lists). If you change the `get_prob` definition to `get_prob(args)` to take a list of strings rather than an unknown number of arguments, the code can be simplified to

```
probs = df['Sequence'].str.split(',').apply(get_prob)
```

which should be a bit faster.

Comment: works great! could you perhaps explain how it works?